# INSERT SELECT * FROM ON DUPLICATE Results in Error 1136

Tags: mysql, python-2.7, pandas, bulkinsert, on-duplicate-key

I am attempting to insert/update a df into a mysql table. I'm receiving this error

> "_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1136, "Column count doesn't  match value count at row 1")"

on the execute line in the code below. Any suggestions on a workaround or a better way?

```
db = MySQLdb.connect(
  host = "myhost",
  user = "username",
  passwd = "password",
  db = "mydb",
  charset='utf8'
 )

df.to_sql(con=db, name='t', if_exists='replace', flavor='mysql')

sqlStatement = """INSERT INTO db.films SELECT t.* FROM db.t
            ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
            films.releasedP=t.releasedP,
            films.runtimeP=t.runtimeP,
            films.imdbRatingP=t.imdbRatingP,
            films.votesYearP=t.votesYearP,
            films.years=t.years,
            films.votesYear=t.votesYear
            ;"""

cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute(sqlStatement)
db.commit()
```

This is the schema of the tables I am attempting to insert/update data.

```
DESCRIBE db.t;

+----------------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                      | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Title                      | varchar(63) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| imdbID                     | varchar(63) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Released                   | varchar(63) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Runtime                    | varchar(63) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| imdbRating                 | varchar(63) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| imdbVotes                  | varchar(63) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| releasedDateTime           | datetime    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| maxDateTime                | datetime    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| years                      | float       | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| votesYear                  | float       | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| rating                     | float       | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| runtimeF                   | float       | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| releasedP                  | float       | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| runtimeP                   | float       | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| imdbRatingP                | float       | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| votesYearP                 | float       | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+----------------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

DESCRIBE db.films;

+----------------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                      | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Actors                     | varchar(63) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Awards                     | varchar(63) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Country                    | varchar(63) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Director                   | varchar(63) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Genre                      | varchar(63) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Language                   | varchar(63) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Metascore                  | varchar(63) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Plot                       | varchar(63) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Poster                     | varchar(63) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Rated                      | varchar(63) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Released                   | varchar(63) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Response                   | varchar(63) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Runtime                    | varchar(63) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Title                      | varchar(63) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Type                       | varchar(63) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Writer                     | varchar(63) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Year                       | varchar(63) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| imdbID                     | varchar(63) | YES  | UNI | NULL    |       |
| imdbRating                 | varchar(63) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| imdbVotes                  | varchar(63) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| years                      | float       | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| votesYear                  | float       | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| rating                     | float       | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| runtimeF                   | float       | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| releasedP                  | float       | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| runtimeP                   | float       | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| imdbRatingP                | float       | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| votesYearP                 | float       | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| releasedDateTime           | datetime    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| maxDateTime                | datetime    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+----------------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Comment: What is the schema for table `db.t`? Is seams that the two table schemas do not match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The schemas of the tables `db.films` and `db.t` do not match. So you need to define wich columns of table `db.films` will be set to wich value from table ``.

Try this query:

```sql
INSERT INTO db.films (
  Title,
  imdbID,
  Released,
  Runtime,
  imdbRating,
  imdbVotes,
  releasedDateTime,
  maxDateTime,
  years,
  votesYear,
  rating,
  runtimeF,
  releasedP,
  runtimeP,
  imdbRatingP,
  votesYearP
)
SELECT
  Title,
  imdbID,
  Released,
  Runtime,
  imdbRating,
  imdbVotes,
  releasedDateTime,
  maxDateTime,
  years,
  votesYear,
  rating,
  runtimeF,
  releasedP,
  runtimeP,
  imdbRatingP,
  votesYearP
FROM db.t
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
  films.releasedP=t.releasedP,
  films.runtimeP=t.runtimeP,
  films.imdbRatingP=t.imdbRatingP,
  films.votesYearP=t.votesYearP,
  films.years=t.years,
  films.votesYear=t.votesYear
```

Comment: I'm sorry Paul, but that was a typo on my behalf which I updated. The fields do match.

Comment: You have updated the question while i was writing the answer. I now updated the answer too.

Comment: Thanks, FYI: I just needed to specify the INSERT INTO fields as it still works with the asterisk in the SELECT part of the statement.

Comment: I know, it works now. But think about, what will happen, if you or  someone else decide to reorder the attributes in the object for table t.